# Trouble in making enemy targets in JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, html

I made a test game where a guy shoots another guy, that's pretty much it.
The problem is I can't properly target the enemy. I'll show you what I mean:

[image: game animation]

As you see, the bullets hit the enemy fine, but they still hit it even when I go down, the bullets hit when their `style.left` is equal to the enemy's `style.left`. I tried to add another exception like this: `If(bullet.style.left == document.getElementById("foe").style.left && bullet.style.top >= document.getElementById("foe").style.top)` and it doesn't work..

I'm sure that I'm making a pretty stupid mistake here.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dg89c/2/

Comment: Whats the problem exactly? What does "but they still hit it even when I go down" mean?

Comment: You can see the problem in the gif that I sent, basically the bullet doesn't need to hit the enemy for it to damage him, as long as the bullet's X position (Style.Left) matches the enemy's X position, it will still damage him. What I want is for the bullet to damage the enemy only if it directly hits him (the bullet touches the area near the enemy including his body), but I can't figure out how to define this area, how to make the enemy the target. Hope that cleared it up.

Answer (score -1):

well..The target seems to me to be top=0 and the bullet will always be top>0 as it is below the target.
0,0 of the screen is top left. As u go down, top increases. U read this vale (top:x) as x distance from top of page.

Comment: The target's top is 100px, the bullet's top is 135px (at starting point). I tried shooting above and below the enemy, in both cases it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You have a hit if the bullet's `top` is between (in pseudocode) `enemy.top` and `enemy.top + enemy.height`. Otherwise, it's not a hit.

Comment: Yes. Can you please write the code for me (or atleast an example of it).